# How cain i position my NavBar logo and Button at center (vertical alignment) of it?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Im fairly new to Web Development and i couldn't apply correctly the solutions that i've found about this problem im having. Im making a responsive website, with a mobile and desktop version, for the desktop version i've managed to make the correct alignment of the logo with the NavBar, but the mobile version of the NavBar has it Logo and Button below its center, and i couldn't correct it.

I've tried a lot of things, like: "justify-items, content: center", "align-items, content: center", i've tried to create an "id" just for the logo and the button, but even doing that, i couldn't place the logo and button at the center of NavBar at all.

```css
#navbar {
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 10px rgb(173, 65, 150);
  height: 100px;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  color: #7a7a7a;
}


/* #navbar a:active {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #050505;
    } */

#navbar a {
  color: #FFF;
}


/* .navbar-brand {
        display: flex;
        position: absolute;   
    } */

.navbar-brand {
  display: flex;
}

.navbar-brand img {
  height: 95px;
}

.navbar-brand span {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
  align-items: center;
  color: #FFF;
}

#navbar-items .navbar-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

#navbar-items .nav-item {
  margin: 0 1em;
}

@media(min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-brand span {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin-left: 0.5em;
    margin-top: 0.7em;
    align-items: center;
    color: #FFF;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top bg-primary-color" id="navbar">
  <div class="container py-3">
    <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand primary-color">
      <img src="img/logocarol3.PNG" alt="Carol Rocha">
      <span>Carol Rocha</span>
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbar-items" aria-controls="navbar-items" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <i class="bi bi-list"></i>
                </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-items">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="index.html" class="nav-link active primary-color" aria-current="page">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="meuscursos.html" class="nav-link primary-color">Meus Cursos</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="contatos.html" class="nav-link primary-color">Contatos</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

And Here is the picture of the problem:
[image: current output]

Comment: hello Davi. Are you using any frameworks? Is there any relevant css?

Comment: Your CSS needed to fix the issue.

Comment: @FujiRoyale Yes, i used some bootstrap5 elements! But i've not just copy and paste, i've modifield somethings, like the NavBar itself and the CSS. I posted the CSS code in the edited quiestion, i forgoted about it!

Comment: @Nikkkshit Yes, i've posted it in the Question now, i've forgoted about it!

Comment: And the desired outcome is that logo and title to be where? Just where it is but vertically centered?